# Identically shuffle multiple arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I am making a quiz game.
I need to shuffle the arrays so that the questions, options, and answer arrays don't appear in order.

Here are the three arrays.

```
public string[] EasyQuestions = 
{
    "What is the capital of Australia?",
    "Who was Steve Jobs?",
    "What number Apollo took Neil Armstrong to the moon?",
    "Which metal is heavier, silver or gold?",
    "What country has the largest population?"
};

public string[] EasyOptions = 
{
    "Brisbane |Canberra |Adelaide |Australian Capital Territory",
    "CEO of Microsoft |Co-founder of Apple |Creator of IBM |Australian Politician",
    "10|11|12|1",
    "Silver|Gold|Gold|Silver",
    "'Murica|China|India|Australia"
};

public string[] EasyAnswers = 
{
    "Canberra",
    "Apple",
    "11",
    "Gold",
    "China"
};
```

I want all of the arrays to be shuffled identically so I don't get wrong answers with different options and different questions?

Comment: Perhaps you should look at creating classes for these things to make it easier on yourself.

Comment: I agree, make a `QuizEntry` class that has `Question`, `Options`, and `Answer` properties. Instantiate instances of this class, assign the values, throw them into a collection, then it becomes _trivial_ to shuffle them.

Comment: How could I achieve this, any links. I thought of doing this, but had no idea how and what it is exactly called, I've only been programming for 6 months xD

Comment: @Trontor: Creating classes is a fundamental, basic part of C#. https://www.google.ca/#q=C%23+class+tutorial

Comment: Thank you! I'll educate myself on it.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Could you elaborate how doing this makes shuffling trivial?

Comment: @Trontor: With the question, options and correct answer all bundled together, you no longer have to worry about keeping three different arrays in sync.  Wherever one piece of the information goes, the rest follow.

Comment: @cHao Does this eliminate the need to shuffle at all, or do I still need to shuffle 1

Comment: @Trontor: If you want random order, then yes, you still have to shuffle.  But you don't have to shuffle three arrays -- just one -- so keeping stuff in sync becomes a non-issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). It shuffles the elements in a single pass.

```
Random rnd = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < EasyQuestions.Length - 1; i++) {
    int j = rnd.Next(i, EasyQuestions.Length);

    string temp = EasyQuestions[j];
    EasyQuestions[j] = EasyQuestions[i];
    EasyQuestions[i] = temp;

    temp = EasyOptions[j];
    EasyOptions[j] = EasyOptions[i];
    EasyOptions[i] = temp;

    temp = EasyAnswers[j];
    EasyAnswers[j] = EasyAnswers[i];
    EasyAnswers[i] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this answered my question, so I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: What is the images array...?

Comment: Sorry, should be any of your arrays.

Answer (score 4):

As I suggested in the comment, if you group everything together then you don't need to worry about keeping things in sync:

```
public class Question {

    private List<string> answers;

    public Question(string text, IEnumerable<string> answers, int answer) {
        this.Text = text;
        this.Answer = answer;

        this.answers = new List<string>(answers);
    }

    public string Text {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public int Answer {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Answers {
        get {
            return this.answers;
        }
    }

    public string GetAnswer() {
        return this.answers[this.Answer];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, so this is how you do properties and such. Even though this doesn't directly answer my question, it is greatly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Could you mind explaining how this eliminates the need of shuffling?

Comment: It doesn't, if you want to randomize it you'd still need to shuffle the collection, but you only have to shuffle a single collection. Then you also have the added benefit of having a logical data structure, instead of having a few disparate arrays, one with pipe separated values (gross).

Answer (score 0):

Don't shuffle the arrays themselves. Instead, shuffle a list of integers containing 0 through 4. Since this appears to be homework I'll let you figure out how to then use that shuffled list.

Comment: It isn't homework, I self-teach myself programming (Year 9), programming isn't part of our curriculum 8)